# Java Servlet getParameter for a param that is a URL

Tags: java, url, servlets, parameters, encode

I am building a site which submits a url to a servlet for analysis purposes. On the client side, I submit the url as a parameter that is encoded. For example...

```
Submit: http://www.site.com
Goes to: http://localhost/myservlet/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site.com
```

On the server side, I have my servlet request the parameter like so...

```
String url = request.getParameter("url");
```

What I receive is a decoded string: http://www.site.com. So far so good -- this works as expected... most of the time.

The problem occurs when a url param contains parameters of its own...

```
Submit: http://www.site.com?param1=1&param2=2
Goes to: http://localhost/myservlet/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site.com%3Fparam1%3D1%26param2%3D2
```

Everything is fine on the client site, but in my servlet when I get the parameter I receive only part of the url param!

```
http://www.site.com?param1=1
```

It dropped the second param from my input url param! I am definitely encoding the url param before submitting it to the server... what is going on?

Comment: Can't reproduce this on Tomcat 6.0.29. Which servletcontainer?

Comment: Using Tomcat 6.0.29. My servlet is extending HttpServlet.

Comment: same as BalusC, I cant reproduce your error in tomcat 5.5 or 6. There was no need to encode/decode any of the text. Can you show us your client side code/form?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem on Tomcat 6.0.29. There's more at matter. Maybe a Filter in the chain which is doing something with the request object?

Anyway, here's a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) in flavor of a single JSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a href="?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site.com%3Fparam1%3D1%26param2%3D2">click here</a>
        <p>URL: ${param.url}
    </body>
</html>
```

Copy'n'paste'n'run it and click the link. Right here I see the following result:

> click here
>
> URL: http://www.site.com?param1=1&param2=2

The same is reproducible with a simple servlet like this which is invoked directly by browser address bar:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.getWriter().write(request.getParameter("url"));
}
```

Tomcat is by the way configured with `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` in HTTP connector, but even with `ISO-8859-1` (which is the default), the behaviour is -as expected in this particular case- the same.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I was submitting my url (via a form) to another page. The second page was employing an ajax call to the server. In the process, the url was decoded, so I have to recode once again before making my call to the servlet.